# CSS grid with scrollable row that expands

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a css grid with a single column and two rows.

I want the first row to expand when there is space and to scroll when there is no space.

I want the second row to remain at the bottom of the div.

I have tried using `display: flex;` in the first row.

HTML:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="top">my<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content</span>
  <span class="bottom">always visible</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 0fr;
}

.top {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span {
  border: solid; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9re86f2a/

I expect the first row to scroll when there is no space, but it actually remains the same size.

---

### [image: row-shrink]

I expect the first row to expand when there is space, but it actually remains the same size.

---

### [image: row-expand]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the flex model for this kind of behavior even if grid does it fine ;)

```css
html * {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0.25em;
  margin:0;
}
body {
  height:100vh;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.top {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;

  /* style aside */
  background:lightblue;
  margin:2px;/* or 0 */
  border:solid;
}
.bottom {
  flex-shrink: 0;

  /* style aside */
  background:tomato;
  margin:2px;/* or 0 */
  border:solid;
}
 /* demo purpose */
.top .demo {
  display: block;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1.5s;
}
.top:hover .demo {
  max-height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="top"><b>Hover me to show my long content</b>
  <span class="demo"><br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content</span>
  </span>
  <span class="bottom">always visible</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing in your code that triggers an overflow condition.

In order for content to overflow, it needs to exceed a width or height limitation (e.g. `height: 300px`), which then triggers the scrollbar.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or `white-space` set to `nowrap`.

In other words, without a fixed height, you won't get the vertical scrollbar... *in Chrome!* Ironically, however, in Firefox, a product of MDN, and Edge, the MDN rule above doesn't apply, and your layout works just fine.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 0fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.top {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

span {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="top">my<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content<br>long<br>long<br>long<br>content</span>
  <span class="bottom">always visible</span>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fc1Lmtq3/1/)

---

***Note on browser rendering differences:*** I can only speculate as to why Firefox and Edge render a scrollbar on a block-level container that doesn't have a defined height or max-height, as specified by MDN (see above). They could be engaging in an [**intervention**](https://github.com/WICG/interventions) or may have a different interpretation of the [**specification**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties) than the MDN contributors.