# How do I get a scrolling list in a css grid cell

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to use css grids for my layout, but I am having trouble getting content to scroll within a grid cell:

In the code below, my goal is to have the parent container 100% visible, have containers for child1 and child2 to consume about half the space each (the grid), and the lists within child1 and child2 to scroll.

I COULD calculate a height for .parent since it is 100% of the offset parent, but calculating the height of the list-container divs, as assigned by the grid?  Without a height the list-containers won't scroll.

I have a stack blitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hytrwz

```
<style>
    .main {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 20em;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 4px;
        border: 1px red solid;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .parent {
        height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 6px;
        border: 1px blue solid;
        padding: 2px;
    }

    .child {
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px green solid;
    }

    .w100 {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<div id="app">
    <main id="calculated-height" class="main">
        <div id="src-cite" class="w100">
            <div id="grid-defined2" class="parent w100">
                <div id="list1" class="list-container w100">
                    <div class="child child1">
                        <div>1</div>
                        <div>2</div>
                        <div>3</div>
                        <div>4</div>
                        <div>5</div>
                        <div>6</div>
                        <div>7</div>
                        <div>8</div>
                        <div>9</div>
                        <div>10</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="list2" class="list-container">
                    <div class="child child2">
                        <div>B1</div>
                        <div>B2</div>
                        <div>B3</div>
                        <div>B4</div>
                        <div>B5</div>
                        <div>B6</div>
                        <div>B7</div>
                        <div>B8</div>
                        <div>B9</div>
                        <div>B10</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

I have spent a couple of days pondering and playing with this. I have not had any more luck trying to solve the problem with the flexbox.

Any help appreciated.

What looks like unnecessary container divs are meant to simulate some component wrappers I have no control over.

Comment: Try `.list-container{ overflow:auto; }`

Comment: The problem you're encountering is that a height limitation is essential if you want to trigger an overflow condition. Without the height limitation, how would the element know when to generate the scrollbars?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57911335/3597276

Comment: That I knew.  How do I overcome that if the height is fluid becuase its in a grid cell that can grow/shrink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, is this you are looking for? Haven't change HTML, only CSS.

**UPDATE 3**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  /* better to use min-height to body. here only to demonstrate */
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20em;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#src-cite {
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  padding: 2px;
}

.list-container {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px green solid;
}

.w100 {}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <main id="calculated-height" class="main">
    <div id="src-cite" class="w100">
      <div id="grid-defined2" class="parent w100">
        <div id="list1" class="list-container w100">
          <div class="child child1">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>10</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="list2" class="list-container">
          <div class="child child2">
            <div>B1</div>
            <div>B2</div>
            <div>B3</div>
            <div>B4</div>
            <div>B5</div>
            <div>B6</div>
            <div>B7</div>
            <div>B8</div>
            <div>B9</div>
            <div>B10</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: The first one doesn't scroll the list, it scrolls the list container (component).  The second one scrolls the parent instead of the individual lists.  Thanks for the try!

Comment: Updated an answer. Look please. I hope this is it.

Comment: The scrolling is correct, but the child containers don't shrink with the grid.

Comment: Updated one more time. Now it is my personal challenge to solve your issue!) Take a look. Parent container now 100% height. Please, if i'm misunderstanding something - tell me what is left to do to reach you goal.